# Can I allow push but not force-push for master branch on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, git-push

We have GitLab 8.6.0-ee at work.

I have a couple of new projects I'm creating, where I want to allow developers to push to master, but I don't want to allow force-push.

But if I go the Protected Branches tab and check "Allow developers to push" next to the protected master branch, the only thing resembling an OK button says "unprotect". And when I click it, master is no longer listed as protected.

I have no other branches at this point. Is there a way to allow developers to push to master but not allow force push or deletion of the branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [original design of protected branches](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/), no: the developers should have the role of master in order to be allowed to push (but not force push or delete the branch) ([as explained here](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/))

A feature request [Introduce a 'Allowed to Force Push' option to the Protected branches](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20742) is still pending.

A workaround would be to have two repos: one where the developers are master and can push to master.
One representing the official repo, which can accepts merge request from the first one in order to update master.

Comment: Thank you, that will work for me.  I will grant the developers master role in these projects.